# q/KDB - nprev function to get all the previous n elements

Tags: kdb

I am struggling to write a `nprev` function in KDB; `xprev` function returns the nth element but I need all the prev `n` elements relative to the current element.

```
q)t:([] i:1+til 26; s:.Q.a)

q)update xp:xprev[3;]s,p:prev s from t
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xprev` function basically looks like this :

```
xprev1:{y til[count y]-x}    //readable xprev
```

We can tweak it to get all `n` elements

```
nprev:{y til[count y]-\:1+til x}
```

using `nprev` in the query

```
q)update np: nprev[3;s] , xp1:xprev1[3;s] , xp: xprev[3;s], p:prev[s]  from t
i  s np    xp1 xp p
-------------------
1  a "   "         
2  b "a  "        a
3  c "ba "        b
4  d "cba" a   a  c
5  e "dcb" b   b  d
6  f "edc" c   c  e
```

k equivalent of `nprev`

```
k)nprev:{$[0h>@y;'`rank;y(!#y)-\:1+!x]}
```

and similarly `nnext` would look like

```
k)nnext:{$[0h>@y;'`rank;y(!#y)+\:1+!x]}
```

Comment: There's also some general sliding-window functionality documented here: http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/programming-idioms/#how-do-i-apply-a-function-to-a-sequence-sliding-window

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result by applying `prev` repeatedly and flipping the result

```
q)n:3
q)select flip 1_prev\[n;s] from t
s
-----
"   "
"a  "
"ba "
"cba"
"dcb"
"edc"
..
```

If `n` is much smaller than the rows count, this will be faster than some of the more straightforward solutions.