# Using 'nprev' with a dynamic input for 'x'

Tags: kdb

I am wanting to use an `nprev` function in lieu of `xprev` in order to return the previous `x` items rather than just one that is `x` indices before.

Through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614230/q-kdb-nprev-function-to-get-all-the-previous-n-elements), I have found an easy way to express the `nprev` function as below:

```
nprev:{y til[count y]-\:1+til x}
```

And this works tremendously as long as you pass an actual number for the `x` input:

```
t:([] numb:0 1 2 3 4; symb:`LA`NY`LA`LA`CH);
t:update npre:nprev[2;symb] from t;
t;

 numb |  symb |   npre   |
---------------------------
   0  |  `LA  |  ``      |
   1  |  `NY  |  `LA`    |
   2  |  `LA  |  `NY`LA  |
   3  |  `LA  |  `LA`NY  |
   4  |  `CH  |  `LA`LA  |
```

However, if say I want to pass a dynamic `x` input such as the column `numb`:

```
t:update npre:nprev[numb;symb] from t;
```

I attain a `type: Mistmatched types` error regardless of what type I cast to the `numb` column. I don't quite understand why this is occuring since `numb` is a `long` type just as the function requires, but I have a feeling the way I defined the function limits me using objects rather than actual numbers, maybe due to the `til`?

I would appreciate any help on this matter to make the above piece of code work, thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, use `max` to keep all `nprev` for a given row

```
q)update npre:nprev[max numb;symb] from t
numb symb npre
---------------------
0    LA
1    NY   LA
2    LA   NY LA
3    LA   LA NY LA
4    CH   LA LA NY LA
```

Longer answer, is that `nprev` expects two vectors arguments and creates a matrix which is applied to the syms to select; negative values return nothing.

It's best viewed outside of the table structure as follows:

```
q)syms:t[`symb]

q)cnt:4

q)til[count syms]-\:1+til cnt
-1 -2 -3 -4
0  -1 -2 -3
1  0  -1 -2
2  1  0  -1
3  2  1  0

q)syms til[count syms]-\:1+til cnt

LA
NY LA
LA NY LA
LA LA NY LA
```

If you want to apply `nprev` with a different value for nprev per row, you'll need to adjust the function and apply on a per row basis.

Perhaps you could try using the following and run a few times with the random to see the steps calculated for each

```
q)update res:{x (y-z)+til z}[symb]'[i;numb] from update numb:5?0+til 5 from t
numb symb res
----------------------
0    LA   `symbol$()
0    NY   `symbol$()
0    LA   `symbol$()
3    LA   `LA`NY`LA
4    CH   `LA`NY`LA`LA
```

Comment: "If you want to apply nprev with a different value for nprev per row, you'll need to adjust the function and apply on a per row basis." That is exactly what I am after thank you for clarifying, but I am just not sure how I would be able to achieve that and if it is an easy implementation or quite complex. Any thoughts?

Comment: @vicefreak04 updated the example above with a possible solution. Let me know if this suits you case. You can remove the null symbols with an extra update where you've requested more prev steps than available

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for all of the previous symbols to appear in reverse order you can forgo a `prev` function variant and just use:

```
q)update npre:reverse each prev(,\)symb from t
numb symb npre
----------------------
0    LA   `symbol$()
1    NY   ,`LA
2    LA   `NY`LA
3    LA   `LA`NY`LA
4    CH   `LA`LA`NY`LA
```

Of course this won't work in the case where the `numb` column does not always equal the virtual index `i` column.